# Why is reading data from Firebase realtime database so slow in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

The time to 'setText' on UI after reading data from Firebase in Android Studio is too slow.
Data read appears about 4 seconds after the screen is loaded.

This is my code.

```
TextView placeName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);

String uid= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference myRef= reference.child("UserAccount:").child(uid).child("companyName");
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot != null){
                String companyName= snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                placeName.setText(companyName);
            }else{
                placeName.setText("snapshot is null");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

I tried to put the code in onStart(), but it still takes about 2 seconds.

Isn't there a way to make it appear immediately like other textViews as soon as the screen is turned over?

Comment: What you can do is to hide that TextView until the onDataChange gets called and then put it visible and with the correct data, so you don't see a TextView empty for X seconds.

Comment: This normally happens when multiple calls are being made to the same data location and they are not resolved until they time out. Make sure your app only calls the database once and does not re-render components that would actively re-call the database. this includes views, widgets, and other dynamically rendered elements

Comment: If this is the first time that your app accesses the database, this is not uncommon as the client has to find the connection to the right server. Subsequent reads should be a lot faster in that case though.